# Sending redirect to function rather than url

Tags: java

I have the following function:

```
@GetMapping("/auth/login")
public String loginFunction(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    return "login";
}
```

Is it possible in another function to call the function rather than the url path? Currently I'm doing:

```
response.sendRedirect("/auth/login");
```

But would prefer to do:

```
response.sendRedirect(loginFunction)
```

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: *Curious:* Why are you casting return value from `sendRedirect`?

Comment: @Andreas Yes it is possible. If the function you are using returns a String.

Comment: @Gatusko That would not do what OP is asking for. OP wants to send a redirect that will cause a new request to call the function in question, not to call the function and have the function return a URL to ... itself? OP is not eliminating the *redirect*.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Spring MVC url-mapped methods are just methods.

You can call from other methods. don't redirect, just call.

```
@GetMapping("/anotherMethod")
public String anotherMethod(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    // response.sendRedirect("/auth/login"); you can redirect 
    return loginFunction(request, model);
}
```

If this isn't what you expected, please post the calling part of your code.